# Any good SharpNEAT tutorial?

Tags: c#, neural-network, neat

[SharpNEAT](http://sharpneat.sourceforge.net/index.htm) is a [NeuroEvolution of Augmenting Topologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NeuroEvolution_of_Augmented_Topologies) (NEAT) library in C#.

The whole thing sounds pretty exciting but I can't find a damn sample/tutorial anywhere!

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just wrote a tutorial for SharpNEAT 2: http://www.nashcoding.com/?p=90

There are going to be at least two more follow-ups, covering co-evolution and HyperNEAT, but part 1 is enough to handle most experiments.

Comment: I know it's been quite some time since this was asked and the tutorial was posted but as it is still the only SharpNeat tutorial out there I should probably mention that there some issues with part 3 (HyperNEAT) of the tutorial. It would be great if you could update it at some point because using these frameworks are really non-trivial.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried SharpNEAT, but I have played with a few of the java variants. I don't really know of any tutorials out there, most of them are just the way-too-simple XOR function.

Is there a specific question/problem you are trying to solve? Perhaps we could brainstorm a solution (to be fair I'm also relatively new at NEAT tho, but perhaps two minds are better than one? :-))

Comment: I don't have any specific problem in mind - I am just very interested in exploring the potential of neuroevolution with NEAT - looking for tutorials just to get an idea of some real-world application. It's fascinating that neuroevolution is the same process from which the human brain evolved!

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't right now, but if you look at the source code and some of the existing experiments then hopefully it's fairly obvious how a problem domain is implemented and plugged in to the main neuro-evolution 'engine'. It's something I have noted for the future though.

You may also be interested in the Version 2 rewrite, currently in a pre-alpha phase but the source is available from the sharpneat website (news/releases section).